# Convert fahrenheit in celsius in MS Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, calculator

I am not a Windows user, but we need to find a solution for converting Fahrenheit in Celsius degrees in MS Windows Vista?

I know that it should be possible using a formula, but is there any *native* way to make this conversion using the built-in calculator application?
Note that I am **not** looking for alternatives but I just want to know if this is possible in Vista.

While it's available in Windows 7, 8 it's not available in Vista.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=98.6F+to+C or https://www.google.com/?q=98.6F+to+C

Comment: @wilson I was just looking for a solution for  Vista built-in calculator app.

Comment: I noticed. That's why I put it as comment instead of answer for your reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available in the included calculator application. I'm using Windows 8, <strike>but i think it's the same in Windows Vista.</strike>
[image: Windows 8 Screenshot - Just press Ctrl+U]

You only need to press Ctrl+U.

**Update**: Looks like this answer is not correct. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_%28Windows%29#Windows_7), the unit conversion feature comes with Windows 7.

**Alternatives**: While it's not built-in, you can download a third-party calculator instead. For example, i found this [Conversion Calculator](http://download.cnet.com/Conversion-Calculator/3000-2056_4-10068809.html). In the web, there are a lot of sites for these as well. Even Google is one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the issue! While it's available in Windows 7, 8 it's not available in Vista. Tested and it won't work.

Comment: Just updated my answer as well!

Comment: Can you copy-paste the Wikipedia paragraph? I don't find it...

Comment: @IonicăBizău It's in the Windows 7 section.

Comment: You should correct the complete answer then. It is clear that Vista still ships with the XP / previous calc.exe

Comment: @PacMani Huh? I thought i have an answer right there?

Comment: @aIKid I think he missed the "Update" at the bottom.  The top of your answer still still says "i think it's the same in Windows Vista"

Comment: @alKid: yeah, the image and the first sentences give a Windows Vista user the false impression that he has the Windows 7 calculator, you should remove that part probably.

Answer (score 9):

[image]You can simply do this using Google.
just type it as below

**1 Fahrenheit = Celsius**

and it will show an online converter where you can even enter custom values.

This can also be used to do different other conversions. I use it to to USD to INR conversion.

**1 USD = INR**

All the best.

Comment: It also understands `1F to C`, which might be easier to remember

Comment: And also `1F in C`

Answer (score 3):

You could use your Web Browser for this...

chrome and firefox have some extensions / addons for unit conversion,

Chrome: [ **[Cloudy Calculator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloudy-calculator/acgimceffoceigocablmjdpebeodphgc)** ] :: 112,931 users / **Rating 5/5** from 1353 users.

Firefox: [ **[Converter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/converter/?src=search)** ] :: 11,911 users / **Rating 5/5** from 51 user reviews.

or

you could use a gadget for this if you prefer... [ [gadget link](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/Unit-Converter-Windows-Gadget,0301-51396.html) ]:

[image] [image]